# need to create a .bat file that creates another .bat file with certain parameters

Tags: batch-file

I have not created complex .bat files in years and my knowledge has left me.

what i need to do is have a .bat file create another .bat file that will be used to run a program with specified arguments.

for example:

.bat file creates a .bat file that contains:

myprogram.exe arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg 5 "arg5" currenttimedatehour currenttimedatehour+1hour

for "arg5" - this argument must be inside ""
for currenttimedatehour it needs to be in YYYY-MM-DD-HHHH format EX: 2012-02-25-1800
for currenttimedatehour+1hour it needs to be in YYYY-MM-DD-HHHH format : 2012-02-25-1900 (whatever current time is plus 1 hour)

when i try to use the simple 
ECHO myprogram.exe arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg 5 "arg5" currenttimedatehour currenttimedatehour+1hour > myfile.bat it acts as if it is trying to run "myprogram.exe" instead of writing it to the output myfile.bat

i have not attempted the currenttimedatehour part as i have no clue how to have it look at the current date and time and format it in the format needed, much less add an hour to it?

can this be done with .bat file? if so, would anyone be so kind to share their knowledge and examples of how i can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a "batch generator" like this (gen.bat) :

```
@echo off

set Y=%date:~10,4%
set M=%date:~4,2%
set D=%date:~7,2%

set /a H=%time:~0,2%
set /a HplusOne=%H+1

set curtime=%Y%-%M%-%D%-%H%00
set curtimePlusOne=%Y%-%M%-%D%-%HplusOne%00

echo myprogram.exe %1 %2 %3 %4 "%5" %curtime% %curtimePlusOne% > caller.bat
```

It gathers 5 parameters and generate a new batch file called "caller.bat", what you should ensure is if date and time format is the same as mine (maybe not.. that's the funny part to edit char positions to extract year/month/day etc.). For testing purpose, you may echo %date% and %time% to get the correct positions if it's not.

Now, let's make a tester (gentest.bat) :

```
@echo off
gen.bat arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5
```

the output in caller.bat should be

> > myprogram.exe arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 "arg5" 2012-02-24-600 2012-02-24-700

I hope this help

Comment: it seams to work for the most part, it just never creates the output file. I added a pause to the end of it and it displays exactly what i need to write to the output file, but it never creates the file. Your time date format was spot on exactly as i need it. not sure why it will display in the window correctly just wont output to a file. any thoughts? thanks, B

Comment: Well, I got it creating the output file.  it was my typo.  i had the ope " but not the end " in one of my args and this was causing it to not create the file.  as soon as i corrected that all was golden.
thank you so much for your help.
i would vote it up but it wont let me since i have no rep here. :-)
thanks again
B